# Sql declare local variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's my query:

it asks me to declare the scalar variable `@acmd` but did I just do that in previous statement?

```
declare @select nvarchar(100), @from nvarchar(50),
        @where nvarchar(50), @acmd nvarchar(150)    

set @select = 'Select * from Customers'
set @from = ' from Customers'
set @where = 'Where Country=''USA'
set @acmd = @select + @from + @where

exec sp_executeSql @acmd
```

Comment: you are putting 2 times `from customers`

Comment: @POHH - actually, they've got two `from` clauses trying to pull from two separate tables - `customers` and `customerswhere` since they've not left any whitespace in there.

Comment: This is not your actual code, or you're doing a bad job describing the error since this code produces two errors, neither of which say anything about `@acmd`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever didnt noticed that . thanx

Comment: You would get the error you describe if you just execute the last line. You need to execute the entire script at once.

Comment: @Donal or having GO before exec also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues. Setting the `@where` variable should be this:

```
set @where= ' Where Country=''USA'' '
```

Setting `@select` should be:

`set @select='Select * '`

Here is fully corrected SQL:

```
declare @select nvarchar(100),@from nvarchar(50),@where nvarchar(50),@acmd nvarchar(150)    
set @select='Select * '
set @from=' from Customers'
set @where= ' Where Country=''USA'' '
set @acmd=@select+@from+@where
exec sp_executeSql @acmd
```

Also, you need to execute the entire script as one block - not just the last line. The error you describe in the post would only be caused if you just ran the last line on its own. The script needs to be run in its entirety.

Comment: all valid/required corrections, but the error the OP describes has nothing to do with any of these..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli I think OP was just executing the last line. I can reproduce the error by just executing the last line.

Comment: i know. You should probably add some text about that too. (*as that seems to be the main problem*)

Comment: And also: since those are all `NVARCHAR` variable, one should use the `N` prefix when using string literals to make sure they're regarded as Unicode strings: `set @select = N'Select * '`

Answer (score 0):

If you execute your Script the SELECT statement should be,

```
Select * from Customers from CustomersWhere Country='USA
```

Instead of that go with the below Script,

```
declare @select nvarchar(100),@from nvarchar(50),@where nvarchar(50),@acmd nvarchar(150)    

set @select='Select * '

set @from=' from Customers'

set @where= ' Where Country=''USA'''

set @acmd=@select+@from+@where

print @acmd

exec sp_executeSql @acmd
```